# Launch new command line and exucte in that shell

Tags: windows, command-line

This must be a real dumb question. And I cant figure out how.

What I want to do is launch a new command line with some arguments and excute some commands there.

Here is what I have in my .cmd

```
 CMD /k %EnvInstallPath% %wo% %var%

 cd /d %wo%\src
```

When I execute test.cmd, I see that the directory changes to %wo%, but the further cd src is not executed. I need to cd to a directory and execute few other commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run cmd with `/k` the console runs the command and then *resumes with the prompt*. I'm guessing that what you want is to run the command and resume with the next one, so you need to run cmd with `/c` instead.

Answer (score 0):

put the other commands in a different bat file and

```
 start AFewOtherCommands.bat
```

Comment: Hi there...Didnt work. My command line ended at the 

CMD /k %EnvInstallPath% %wo% %var%

When I typed exit, the new cmd window popped up.